# Session still authenticates after server restart?

Tags: flask-login

Ok, so, I'm able to login in a user successfully. And logout. Then force a user to log back in.

What doesn't seem to work is when the user authenticates, does an action that causes the server to restart, then when the server comes back up, the user is still authenticated.

This is on a hardware device, so there's no persistent storage. Somehow maybe python flask login "trusts" the cookie once its sent, always? I feel like I'm not fully understanding what Flask Login is doing...

I have no real user store. There's only one user. Here are some code blocks I have, if it helps anyone:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User(id)

class User(FlaskLogin.UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
```

And the login method itself (some stuff removed of course):

```
def login():
    sysPassword = supersecretmethodherethatreturnspasswordasastring()

    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        password = flask.request.form['password']
        username = flask.request.form['username']

        if password == sysPassword and username == 'static-user-name':
            user = User(username)
            FlaskLogin.login_user(user)
            return flask.redirect("/dashboard")
        else:
            return flask.render_template("login.html", error="Incorrect password. Please enter the correct password.", product=productid, products=defaults.products)

    return flask.render_template("login.html", error=False, product=productid, products=defaults.products)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask-Login is an abstraction over [Flask's sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.sessions.SecureCookieSessionInterface).

Sessions in Flask are [cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). Cookies tend to stick around in the browser. You are free to configure how long sessions live and so forth. But as long as you present a valid session to Flask-Login, you will remain logged in.

The docs cover this [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works).

Comment: Interesting. I'm guessing I need to have `load_user` fail after a device reboot. Need to store some sort of unique key with each login.. HRMM.